# conversion failed when converting [T-SQL / SQL Server]

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Everytime I try to call my Stored Procedure, I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT, Line 16
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'diverse' to data type int.

Some sample values (or a sample call) looks like this:

`exec P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT '','','','','D2335548','','Lindner',''`

I don't understand this error-message at all. What is he refering to with `diverse`. Also, what could possibly go wrong with converting to `INT`? The 2nd and last parameter are `INT`, but even without single quotes, the error-message stays the same.

Just to give you all information, I'll add the Stored Procedure.

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT]
@status tinyint, @jahr int, @cl_vnr bigint, @cl_name nvarchar(50), @sgi nvarchar(20), @gknr nvarchar(4), @gkname varchar(50), @gueltjahr int

AS

if @cl_vnr = '' set @cl_vnr = 0
if @status = '' set @status = 0
if @jahr = '' set @jahr = 0
if @gueltjahr = '' set @gueltjahr = '0'
if @gknr = '' set @gknr = '0'
if @gknr IS NULL set @gknr = '0'


if @gueltjahr = '0'
    select distinct CL_ID, CD_CLVID, CD_VERSION, CL_NAME, CD_JAHR, ST_NAME as CD_STATUS,
        case isNULL(CD_AKTIV,0) when 0 then 'Nein' when 1 then 'Ja' end as CD_AKTIV,
        CD_STATUS as CD_STATUS_ID, CD_VON, CD_BIS 
    from dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER d
    inner join dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER_GK k on d.CD_CLVID = k.KD_CLVID
    left join dbo.T_KB_GK_STATUS on CD_STATUS = ST_ID
    where   d.CL_ART = 'GK'
            and CD_STATUS = case when @status = 0 then CD_STATUS else @status end
            and CD_JAHR = case when @jahr = 0 then CD_JAHR else @jahr end
            and CD_CLVID = case when @cl_vnr = 0 then CD_CLVID else @cl_vnr end
            and CL_NAME like '%' + @cl_name + '%'
            and k.KD_NR = case when @gknr = '0' then k.KD_NR else @gknr end
            and k.GK_KUNDE like '%' + @gkname + '%'
    order by CL_ID, CD_JAHR DESC, CD_VERSION DESC
else
    select distinct CL_ID, CD_CLVID, CD_VERSION, CL_NAME, CD_JAHR, ST_NAME as CD_STATUS,
        case isNULL(CD_AKTIV,0) when 0 then 'Nein' when 1 then 'Ja' end as CD_AKTIV,
        CD_STATUS as CD_STATUS_ID, CD_VON, CD_BIS 
    from dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER d
    inner join dbo.V_KB_CLUSTER_GK k on d.CD_CLVID = k.KD_CLVID
    left join dbo.T_KB_GK_STATUS on CD_STATUS = ST_ID
    where   d.CL_ART = 'GK'
            and CD_STATUS = case when @status = 0 then CD_STATUS else @status end
            and CD_JAHR = case when @jahr = 0 then CD_JAHR else @jahr end
            and CD_CLVID = case when @cl_vnr = 0 then CD_CLVID else @cl_vnr end
            and CL_NAME like '%' + @cl_name + '%'
            and k.KD_NR = case when @gknr = '0' then k.KD_NR else @gknr end
            and k.GK_KUNDE like '%' + @gkname + '%'
            and @gueltjahr between year(CD_VON) and isNULL(year(CD_BIS),@gueltjahr)
    order by CL_ID, CD_JAHR DESC, CD_VERSION DESC
```

I'm using SQL-Server 2008.

**Update**: It doesn't work with numerical values as well:

`exec P_KB_GET_GK_UEBERSICHT 0,0,0,'','D2335548','','Lindner',0`

Comment: Maybe you're calling the stored procedure with parameters in the wrong order. I suppose it receives a varchar 'diverse' where it is expecting an integer, so it tries to cast 'diverse' to int and this failes (because it's obviously not a number).

Also, you are given a line number where the error happens. What's on line 16 exactly?

Comment: I feel like you have the right approach here. It seems like it has something to do with putting those values in quotes.

Comment: What is the data type of column `CD_AKTIV`?

Comment: @Rokuto tinyint

Comment: I am sure that there is a problem with `WHERE`. I don't know why you are comparing your numeric variables with `''` (e.g. `if @cl_vnr = ''`). `@cl_vnr` can be or `NULL` or has value which is number. What are the data types of columns `CD_STATUS`, `CD_CLVID`?

Comment: CD_CLVID = bigint and CD_STATUS tinyint

Comment: Please, exec `SELECT` statement without `WHERE` clause (use `TOP`) and check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to the stored procedure is wrong.  SQL Server is expecting tinyint, int and bigint respectively for the first three parameters, but you are passing '' which is interpreted as a varchar.  Looking at your proc, I think you need to pass all three as 0, if you want the default values.

EDIT

Your SQL is wrong.  Replace

```
if @gueltjahr = '0'
```

With

```
if @gueltjahr = 0
```

Comment: Interesting.. Well, I build a query in `classic-asp`, so while I'm not checking against every value, I roll with `'" & request("myPost") & "'"`. After changing those values to nvarchar() it works, but it feels not right

Comment: Please show your build statement.  You should not be passing these values as varchar.  What you need to do is pass 0 without any surrounding quotation marks and leave them as previously defined in the proc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150388/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-dassaffe).